# if i find out my answer, why do i have to wait 2 days to accept it

Tags: bug, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why must I wait 2 days before accepting my own answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer)

i post a question and after doing more research i find out the answer myself.  At this point i can't actually check off the questions as answered as it makes me wait 2 days

what is the logic here.  now folks will waste time trying to solve this answer which is already solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wait two days to answer your own question so that there can be enough time for somebody to say, "Hey, that's actually not a good solution, and here's why." Often times, the self-solution is not the optimal solution. Giving a two day grace period helps mitigate this.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing to stop you from *posting* the answer, so people will see it for the two days before you're allowed to accept it.

Eric and Jonathan's points are valid, but sometimes I agree it would be nice to be able to accept your own answer immediately - because it's *obviously* right. As an example of this, look at my [Code Contracts question about arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244290/should-the-code-contracts-static-checker-be-able-to-check-arithmetic-bound): I'd asked on the MSDN forum as well, and one of the CC team answered the question. I checked the answer, it worked, I reworded and reposted it on SO.

It's clearly right, so it would make sense to be able to accept it immediately... in this particular case. However, I suspect that the *general principle* of "let the community warn you of problems first" is more important than *specific* cases where immediate acceptance would make sense - so I support the policy overall.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Eric. I personally take it a step further though. When I ask a question that I know very little about, I won't automatically accept the first working solution I receive. My logic, I'm the confused one - why would I trust myself to know when the correct, and best answer has been provided. I don't want to be naive and just accept the first one that doesn't produce an error. So I wait, and let the community vote on it before I accept an answer.

**Example**: [Kohana, .htaccess, and $_GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267989/kohana-htaccess-and-get)

And here's an example of me answering my own question - I'll probably wait until I get other answers, and see some community-voting before I accept an answer, even though my solution works.

[Kohana, Editing Cache doesn't Reflect in View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271630/kohana-editing-cache-doesnt-reflect-in-view)