# Allow accepting my own answer without waiting 48 hours, in light of Accept Rate

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Yes, we [asked for this before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer). Now that you [display our accept rate](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/) (it's in fact a new form of flair, like reputation and badges), this is even more important:

**Let me decide when to accept an answer**

In this case, [I asked a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/57941/error-setting-a-windows-service-logon-user/57959#57959), and after half an hour found the right answer. Now, in order to maintain my accept rate, you're forcing me to revisit this question after 2 days, instead of just accepting my answer now.

Comment: Poor boy. Accept rate will fold you into a crack in the Universe.

Comment: I would make a joke about you just having 25%, but these are already getting old...

Comment: Not only are you being forced to revisit that question, you are also forced to post other questions on other sites. Rats!

Comment: Why does this question not have any accepted answer? Oh the irony...

Comment: @Øystein - it's a feature request. Even though it is not popular, this is the behaviour I would like ... no point in accepting an answer in this case.

Answer (score 17):

Er..

Don't obsess. *Especially* don't obsess over your acceptance rate. You have a whole 24 hours to accept it before it counts towards acceptance rate. No biggie.

It is not that important. Self acceptance is delayed because:

- if you had to ask, you probably weren't the best person to answer the question, so some time is allowed for a more knowledgeable person to show you the error of your ways (if any)
- to give other an incentive to provide a good answer and reap the reward in terms of praise, endorphins, and site-reputation

Comment: Without **high arbitrary numbers** associated with my account, I'm afraid my self-esteem will spiral into a pit of depression and I'll have no choice but to drink myself into a crying heap every night.

Comment: But, Weblog, don't you do that anyway?

Comment: Yeah, but now I'll have a reason to do it.

Comment: @Welbog: You know what? Scratch the spiral into pit of depression part and lets skip right into the drinking part.

Comment: I'm all about people obsessing over the acceptance rate. You wouldn't believe how many check marks I have picked up in the past 48 hours on old topics here on Meta.

Comment: @TheTXI: I maintain that I accepted your answer for the two arbitrary reputation points, not the arbitrary acceptance rate!

Comment: @balpha: Agreed. Since most questions are either feature requests or bug reports, and since the Fortuitous Atwood Team (hereafter referred to as FAT) doesn't reply with actual answers to this type of question, it's hard to accept answers for them. This is FAT's fault. They're so lazy, just replacing tags with `status-lol` instead of actually answering things.

Comment: Hi all, just got out of bed. So, what's going on here?

Comment: Your filthy snot-producing face is mine, balpha!

Answer (score 10):

According to the blog post, questions don't apply to accept rate until they are 3 days old.  So I don't see what the problem is.  You've got 24 hours to accept it before it impacts your accept rate.

Comment: I'm sick of your sensible answers, Pesto! Would it kill you to answer a question incorrectly every once in a while?

Comment: Welbog: Banana.  How's that for an incorrect answer?

Comment: I'm feeling a bit canary about this whole vectorized plane.

Comment: I just don't want to bother to ever return to this question. I know right now what is the right answer, let me accept it.

Comment: @Pesto: You answered the question I had been thinking all morning! "What should I eat as a dessert?"

Comment: @ripper234: What business do you have asking questions that you can answer yourself anyway?

Comment: @Welbog & @Presto: You guys are cracking me up. Keep it coming ;)

Answer (score 5):

> [@ripper234:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16880/allow-accepting-my-own-answer-without-waiting-48-hours-in-light-of-accept-rate/16884#16884) What business do you have asking questions that you can answer yourself anyway? – Welbog 2 mins ago

I think you should check this as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe one question without an accepted answer is reason to change the decision to not allow accepting of your own answers for 48 hours. Yes it will temporarily drop your stats, but one question cannot make the difference between 10% and 70%, and suspect it will be more of a "general range" that is important to most answerers with the acceptance rate and not a specific number.

EDIT: As [Pesto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16880/16884#16884) points out, the blog post states it is 3 days (60 hours) before a question is calculated in, therefore, this should never become an issue. But even if it were, I believe its the general range of acceptance rate you're in that matters far more than having 100% acceptance rate.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that we should be able to accept our answers straight away, once we have sufficient reputation. I sometimes use stack overflow to share the answers to questions that I have solved myself - I solve the question and then immediately answer it. Coming back to accept a solution is a pain.

Comment: Seems we the minority here.

Comment: How about the ability it auto-accept in two days if no-one else answers the question?