# When I find the answer by myself why can't I mark it as Answer?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, answers

it was happend to me in two questions.
i asked the question; and after a lot of effort i found the solution.  but i could not mark my answer as Final Answer.
don't you think this limitation in not necessary?
and what happens to users' points in such cases?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16880/allow-accepting-my-own-answer-without-waiting-48-hours-in-light-of-accept-rate

Comment: @chrisf I would not call that a duplicate, this is "why can't I?" and the other is "I want different behavior." One does not proceed from the other, necessarily.

Comment: @Jeff - fair enough. I'd withdraw my close vote if I could ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accept your own answers after waiting 48 hours.

Comment: oh i didn't know. so it would be a good idea that user be informed about this.

Comment: @takpar - I hate this waiting period.

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16880/allow-accepting-my-own-answer-without-waiting-48-hours-in-light-of-accept-rate