# Can the answer of a Q&A be auto-accepted when both are posted at the same time?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, instant-self-answer

## Catija convinced me: dumb idea. [Thanks for putting me straight!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309159/275497)

---

Original question:

---

Yes, I'm aware of Jeff Atwood's original [blog post](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/12/why-cant-i-accept-my-own-answer/) *from 2008* and the [partial relent](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) *from 2009* and [the other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer) and [another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16880/allow-accepting-my-own-answer-without-waiting-48-hours-in-light-of-accept-rate) and [yet another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21265/auto-accept-self-answer-if-no-other-answers-are-provided-in-two-days)...

***So this question is not about:*** not finding a solution, being exasperated, posting a question and a few minutes or hours later finding a solution and answering, **but it's all about:**

- Having an issue
- Looking into it
- [Talking to people in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44020465#44020465), not getting any solution from the [resident expert](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44044868#44044868)
- Continuing on the road of blood, sweat and tears and [finally finding a solution!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44047536#44047536)
- Someone telling you ["You should write a Q&A about that!"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44047634#44047634)
- Actually writing the question and ticking the box:

  **"Answer your own question -** <sub><sup>[share your knowledge, Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)</sup></sub>"
- [And finally answering at the same time you post your question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines).

***So can we have these kinds of Q&As auto-accepted, please?***

#### Why?

- Answers posted at the same time as their questions have an answer that has been verified to work.
- It's easy to change the acceptance if someone else would come along and writes an awesome answer as the OP gets pinged when a new answer to his question gets posted.
- I'm too busy at work during the day and too busy at night *answering questions* to actually remember and go back and accept my own answer. (I found one about a year ago that I forgot to accept for a few weeks or months or so)
- Jeff Atwood wrote the original in 2008 and partially relented in 2009.  Wouldn't it make sense to review this again nearly a decade later??? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

<sub>OK, I'll settle for the system pinging me you to tell me "Hey, go back and accept your own answer, the 48h waiting period is over and no one else has answered in the meantime!"</sub>

---

### Please? Pretty please with unicorns and rainbows?

[image: Cute Unicorn]

Comment: What difference does it make if an answer is accepted or not? I mean, so you forget to accept your answer. OK. So what?

Comment: *Wouldn't is be a better world if 100% of questions were answered and 100% of all answers would be good enough to get an acceptance?*. well, this is one spit in the bucket.  ***f we can get 1000 more spits, the bucket will be full!  :-)**

Comment: `<pedant>`Answers are answered when they have an answer `</pedant>`. More seriously, they are counted by the system as answered as soon as they have an upvoted answer. Usually (not always, but very, very often) votes are a far better indication of an answer's quality than the accept tick. So what's the benefit here? Could you [edit] your question and clarify why having an accepted answer would be beneficial?

Comment: OK, OK, it was a dumb idea...  I stand corrected.  10 minutes and 4 downvotes, that'll mean I'll be -1 and banned from asking questions in about 16 hours...  **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: @Fabby: The thresholds for bans on meta are significantly relaxed cf. other sites.

Comment: @cl-netbox You did 80% of the work, and I did the last 20.  Too bad about the downvotes that keep pouring in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see no reason for this.

You finding your answer doesn't mean that no one can come up with a better one or explain it better than you can.

While accepting doesn't prevent people from answering *technically* it has been argued for a long time that people are less likely to answer questions that are accepted... so the potential for attracting high-quality content to your question is suppressed. It tells people "I'm happy with this, you needn't bother writing anything else".

On top of that, doing it automatically seems troublesome as users may be unaware that self answers will be automatically accepted and be confused when it occurs, particularly if that wasn't their intention.

Accepts, particularly of self-answers, don't really *do* anything other than tell users their participation is unwanted. You don't get a bonus for accepting, the answer isn't stuck to the top if it's not the highest voted. Until the answer gets some actual buy-in from users, I don't really know that it makes sense to let you instantly accept them... heck, you have to wait fifteen minutes to accept an answer you *didn't* write. At the very minimum, you should have to wait that long.

Perhaps 48 hours is more than necessary - 24 is the guideline I give people when they accept answers too soon on the sites that I use - but instantly doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: ... Huh... That's... kinda dumb. I knew the author couldn't but I was under the impression that only mods could.

Comment: Um... no. Acceptance is not the same as upvoting.

Comment: @Fabby Ask the question you want to ask... I don't see how that has anything to do with this question as written and it seems like you're just spamming links to something else in chat.

Comment: Yup, it was a bad idea. Link to chat removed. See [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/309158/revisions)