# Can I self-accept sooner when I get more reps?

Tags: feature-request, support, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

I self-answered [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7602145/416579), but the system won't let me self-accept my answer unless I wait another 2 days.

Will this limitation be removed when I get more reputation points? If that's not the case, can this limitation be lifted given certain conditions (for example: user has more than 2,000 points and answer has more than a certain amount of upvotes)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Accepting your own answer always requires a two day wait, regardless of reputation.

See also [Why must I wait 2 days before accepting my own answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer)