# How can I improve the wording for the following JavaScript question?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, asking-questions

> **Title: What part of JavaScript syntax is involved when you encounter (code)()?**
>
> I recently encountered a short piece of script for the BASE tag but it
>   was in the form:   (code)()
>
> By this I mean it was a few lines of script, enclosed in parentheses,
>   and followed by an empty set of parentheses.
>
> ```
> <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript">  
>     // Fix for IE ignoring relative base tags.
>     (function() {
>         var baseTag = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0];
>         baseTag.href = baseTag.href;
>     })(); </script><![endif]-->
> ```
>
> per Richard Connamacher at stack overflow at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926197/html-base-tag-and-local-folder-path-with-internet-explorer)
>
> I'm not sure how to research why the parentheses, in particular the second set, are
>   there.  Is it enclosure?

---

What is wrong with this question?  I expect that given I don't know what I was looking at and how to describe it, there are issues.  It is also difficult to search for.  It could even be a syntax error but I doubt it.

I am certain the question is not phrased correctly.  Would it be a mistake to even ask?  More specifically, would it get blocked or down voted?

Comment: Please consider using a quote block or similar to help us understand where the original question ends and where your meta question begins. I'm consistently failing to parse it even though the night's still young.

Comment: I think I extracted and quoted the question you're asking about, which should make this a little easier to parse.

Comment: Brad, quoting the original question was much better than a horizontal line.  Thanks.

Comment: It's an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) - not sure how best to ask the question, though

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I have added the code. Sorry, it took forever to find the post again.  I suspect there is larger issue of how I express the questions rather than what the question actually is.

Comment: @DHorse - sure thing.  The first set of parenthesis turns the function declaration into a function expression, and the second set invokes said function expression: immediately invoked, function expression.  Note that `(function(){ /* code here */ }())` will also work

Comment: AdamRackis Well I didn't expect an actual answer but thanks, never heard of "an immediately invoked function expression."  I now see there are some much more sophisticate scope issues I need to look at.  There you go.  In that light the question seems even more poorly worded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told on another thread that the questions was OK as is including the revisions made so credit ti [frederic-hamidi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/164403/frederic-hamidi) and [brad-larson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135615/brad-larson)

Additional credit to [adam-rackis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155403/adam-rackis) who answered the question rather than improving it.

Additionally credit to [george-cummins](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/165786/george-cummins) who more or less pointed out to not be hypothetical.  Meaning, include the actual code samples here or it is hard to know what might be wrong with the question.

OOPS, I still can't mark the question as answered.  Odd. (see:[Mark a comment as answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question))

Comment: Thank you for crediting us. Re: your last sentence, see [Why must I wait 2 days before accepting my own answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Certainly, thank you, your above post was informative.  One or more of you guys should move your comments into an answer so I can credit it properly (given the type of question this is.)

Comment: With this type of question, I'm really not sure if I should repeatedly refine (edit) my original post.  It is what I am doing.  Of course, the final, postable version would be quite different from the original question asked.  I can think of some alternate strategies.