# Can OP now accept their own answer quickly?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, self-answer

This user self answered [his question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616960/cant-boot-into-linux-dual-boot-hp-goes-directly-to-windows8):

[image]

How did he accept it so quickly? I thought there was a 48 hour delay between posting and accepting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 48 hour delay is between posting the *question* (2015/5/1 16:30) and accepting the *answer* (2015/5/3 20:36). That is 2 days, 4 hours, 6 minutes there.

More info [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer).

Comment: Ahh, I see - I always thought it was answer... I guess because I self answer immediately, with the Q&A style button...