# Where's my 5 minute grace period gone?

Tags: support, edits, grace-period

I just posted an answer. (Revision history [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/255844/revisions).)

I edited it a few seconds later (within my 5 minute grace period), and it comes up as a new revision!? Why?

[image]

^^You can see 'answered **1 min** ago', and then 'edited **1 min** ago' - how is that possible?

Additionally, [it's happened to this question as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/255845/revisions)!?

[image]

I don't think this is a dupe of [Reset question grace period once an answer has been posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted). See my comments on AI.E's answer. If you're a mod, it will really help.

Comment: Because I edited it before. So I'd already created a new revision. It can't include the edits you make after mine before mine, so it splits them up...? Or was this before I edited?

Comment: @Tim Wait? What!? There's a whole *minute's* difference between our posts!

Comment: Yeah, I see your point now! Could it be because of the amount you added?  Does that make a difference?

Comment: @Tim It's happened to this question as well!? What's happening!!!!?? No, it's never made a difference before...

Comment: Post inception!

Comment: But the edit to the edit did combine - so the first grace was ignored, then the second was counted...

Comment: @Tim I see what you're saying, but I've edited posts before *many* times within my grace period and nothing like this has happened!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset question grace period once an answer has been posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As [Al E. correctly mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255845/wheres-my-5-minute-grace-period-gone-happened-to-this-question-as-well/255846#255846), a new feature (implemented in March 2015) creates a new revision rather than rolling it into the previous edit when any one of several specific conditions are met:

> - The previous revision was created 5 minutes or more in the past
> - A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone other than the editor.
> - An answer has been added to the post since the previous revision
> - The previous revision was a rollback
> - The new revision is a rollback

(Source: [Reset question grace period once an answer has been posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted/251876#251876))

But [you seem to dispute](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255845/wheres-my-5-minute-grace-period-gone-happened-to-this-question-as-well#comment833176_255846) that these conditions exist:

> None of those conditions are true for this question though

However, you are incorrect.

For the [answer in question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255843/can-op-now-accept-their-own-answer-quickly/255844#255844), the timestamp on your edit is 20:42:25Z.  The timestamp on Tim's comment was 20:42:22Z.  So while you may have started editing before Tim's comment, his comment beat your edit by 3 seconds.  Once that comment was left, your grace period ended immediately.

And for this question, you have the same exact situation.  Your first edit was committed on 20:46:25Z.  Tim's first comment was at 20:46:24Z, beating your edit by a second.  So again, the grace period ended as soon as Tim left his comment and your edit created a new revision.

Comment: +1 good answer :) ! Side Q - what are the "z" next to the seconds? (I know they correct have seen them around the site)

Comment: @James Z = Zulu, which is a [reference to UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones)

Comment: Thanks :) I did not know about that. Interesting

Answer (score 10):

This is a change from back in March:

[Reset question grace period once an answer has been posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted/251876#251876)

> Edits will be rolled into the previous revision if the previous revision was created by the same author and *none* of the following conditions are present:
>
> - The previous revision was created 5 minutes or more in the past
> - A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone other than the editor.
> - An answer has been added to the post since the previous revision
> - The previous revision was a rollback
> - The new revision is a rollback

So, if someone answers or edits during the 5-minute-window, the grace period is immediately terminated.

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: None of those conditions are true for this question though.

Comment: Sure it is. Tim edited it too.

Comment: Deleted comment? Deleted answer? Only a mod can probably tease it out.

Comment: There wasn't a deleted answer here, there could have been a comment tho...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ there was no deleted comments,  Just bad timing.  You lost the race to posting your edit in both cases by a matter of seconds.