# Prompt when I accept my answer within 2 days seems miswritten?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, self-answer

When I try accept my answer, I see a prompt:

> You can accept your own answer in 2 days

Is this miswritten for "you **can not** accept your own answer in 2 days"?

See also: [Why must I wait two days before accepting my own answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-two-days-before-accepting-my-own-answer)

Comment: It would have to be *... for 2 days* if you use *can not*. Otherwise you imply that I can only accept my own answer in the first two days... ;)

Comment: @MEE I'm sorry, maybe "can not"  not equal to "cannot"?also I post about this [English question in ell](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/192714/you-can-vs-you-cannot-how-to-understanding-what-is-difference)

Comment: @illiterate: "*maybe "can not" not equal to "cannot"?*" They're the same. The problem is that your version says that, 2 days from now, you *cannot* accept the answer. Which is incorrect; you can accept it 2 days from now, but not *now*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In English, "in 2 days" means the same as "after 2 days have passed". So the prompt is correct. Your version would work as "You can not accept your own answer within 2 days after posting the question", but that does not tell you how long you have to wait. (You'll see tomorrow that it will say "in 1 day" or even "in *x* hours".) Therefore, the current version is preferable.